# Object is used but not declared in VHDL

Tags: vhdl, fpga

I'm doing a BCD counter that can count up/down depending on the input signals. This is the requirement:
[image]

This is my VHDL code:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.numeric_std.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;

-- main
entity BCDcounter is
port(
    D_in: in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
    enable_in, load_in, up_in, clr_in, clk_50hz: in std_logic;
    C_out: out std_logic;
    LED0: out std_logic_vector(0 to 6)
);
end BCDcounter;
architecture Behavioral of BCDcounter is

signal Q_temp: std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
signal clk_1hz: std_logic;

component Clock_Divider is
    port ( clk,reset: in std_logic;
        clock_out: out std_logic);
end component;

component BCD_counter is
port(
    D: in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
    enable, load, up, clr, clk: in std_logic;
    Q: std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
    Cout: out std_logic
);
end component;

component led IS
  PORT ( input : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0);
        output : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(6 downto 0));
end component;

begin
stage0: Clock_Divider port map(clk_50hz, clr_in, clk_1hz);
stage1: BCD_counter port map(D_in, enable_in, load_in, up_in, clr_in, clk_1hz, Q_temp, C_out);
stage2: led port map(Q_temp, LED0);

end Behavioral;

-- 1-digit BCD counter
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.numeric_std.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;

entity BCD_counter is
port(
    D: in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
    enable, load, up, clr, clk: in std_logic;
    Q: std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
    Cout: out std_logic
);
end BCD_counter;
architecture bhv of BCDcounter is
signal temp: std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
begin   
   process(enable, load, up, clr, clk)
   begin
      if clr = '0' then
         temp <= "0000";
      elsif enable = '0' then
         temp <= "0000";
      elsif load = '1' then -- load = 1, enable = 1
         temp <= D; 
      elsif(rising_edge(clk)) then -- load = 0, enable = 1
         if up = '1' then -- count up
            if temp = "1001" then
                temp <= "0000";
                Cout <= '1';
            else
                temp <= temp + 1;
            end if;
         else -- count down
            if temp = "0000" then
                temp <= "1001";
                Cout <= '1';
            else
                temp <= temp - 1;
            end if;
         end if;
      end if;
   end process;
Q <= temp;
end bhv;

-- Clock Divider from 50MHz to 1Hz
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.numeric_std.ALL;

entity Clock_Divider is
    port ( clk,reset: in std_logic;
        clock_out: out std_logic);
end Clock_Divider;

architecture behavioral of Clock_Divider is

signal count: integer:=1;
signal tmp : std_logic := '0';
begin
    process(clk,reset)
    begin
        if(reset='1') then
            count <= 1;
            tmp <= '0';
        elsif(clk'event and clk='1') then
            count <= count+1;
            if (count = 25000000) then
                tmp <= NOT tmp;
                count <= 1;
            end if;
        end if;
    clock_out <= tmp;
    end process;
end behavioral;

-- LED 7 segments
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
ENTITY led IS
  PORT ( input : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0);
        output : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(6 downto 0));
END led;
ARCHITECTURE behave OF led IS
BEGIN
  PROCESS(input)
  BEGIN
    CASE input IS           --  abcdefg
        WHEN "0000" => output <= "0000001"; 
        WHEN "0001" => output <= "1001111"; 
        WHEN "0010" => output <= "0010010"; 
        WHEN "0011" => output <= "0000110"; 
        WHEN "0100" => output <= "1001100"; 
        WHEN "0101" => output <= "0100100";
        WHEN "0110" => output <= "0100000";
        WHEN "0111" => output <= "0001111";
        WHEN "1000" => output <= "0000000";
        WHEN "1001" => output <= "0000100";
        WHEN OTHERS => output <= "1111111";-- ALL OFF
      END CASE;
  END PROCESS;
END behave;
```

When compiling, I meet the error like this although I have already declared them above. Can anyone show me what problem with my code and how to fix this error? Thank you so much.
[image]

Comment: See [ask], the bit about images. None of the text revealed in images shows up in search for future readers. The details of your assignment are not necessary to find the errors, Tricky would have analyzed (compiled) your code. Neither Clock_Divider nor led are required to demonstrate the image errors nor the unseen errors for clk, Cout, D, and Q. You have some unnecessary use clauses making IEEE package numeric_std and Synopsys package std_logic_arith declarations directly visible which your code doesn't depend on.

Answer (score 4):

Your entity is called `BCD_counter`

```vhdl
entity BCD_counter is
```

but you have created the architecture for `BCDCounter`

```vhdl
architecture bhv of BCDcounter is
```

And it is quite correct, `BCD_Counter` has no object called `clr` or any of the other objects it lists.

Be careful when naming entities. I also recommend putting one entity/architecture pair per file, with the prefered method to name the file the same as the entity.

Comment: Thank you so much. I fixed that problem and some minor errors. This is my new code, however, I still meet one error: Error (10568): VHDL error at BCDcounter.vhd(91): can't write to interface object "Q" of mode IN. Can you show me how to fix this?

Comment: declare `Q` as `out` : `Q: out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);`. Ports will default to `in` if not given a direction.